# Expand multilinear functions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

From the definition, we know that the multilinear function behaves linearly on one variable when all other variables are fixed. For example, $f(x_1, x_2+x_3, x_4)=f(x_1, x_2, x_4)+f(x_1, x_3, x_4)$.

However, if we know that a function is multilinear and there are more than 1 variables in the calculation, how should we deal with it? For example, if we have $f(x_1, x_2, x_4)+f(x_1, x_4, x_2)$, how should we calculate this as we see both the second and the third are variables? Does this equal $f(x_1 ,x_2+x_4, x_2+x_4)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
f(x_1 ,x_2+x_4, x_2+x_4)
&= f(x_1,x_2,x_2+x_4) + f(x_1,x_4,x_2+x_4) \\
&= f(x_1,x_2,x_2) + f(x_1,x_2,x_4) \\
&\qquad +  f(x_1,x_4,x_2) + f(x_1,x_4,x_4)
\end{align}
which, in general, is not the same as $f(x_1, x_2, x_4)+f(x_1, x_4, x_2)$.